# Cookies not available when not logged in with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in PHP using the `setcookie()` function.

My code is as follows:

`setcookie('key', $key, time() + (86400 * 365), '/');`

I'm using an action hook to show all cookies after the theme is loaded using the following code:

```
function set_devsource_cookie() {

    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "THE IP") {
        print_r($_COOKIE);
    }

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'set_devsource_cookie', 0 );
```

When logged in to Wordpress this shows the all the cookies as expected, but when I'm not logged in to Wordpress it shows an empty array.

**Note that I am using WPEngine as my host, but that caching is disabled.**

Comment: You are aware that cookies will only become available in $_COOKIE with the _next_ request (and not immediately in the one where you _set_ the cookie in the response), right …?

Comment: @CBroe, Yes, I have tried refreshing the page multiple times

Comment: And where is your setcookie call located?

Comment: At the login screen, after the form is submitted the login is checked and the cookie is set if the login is successful.

Comment: So if you are not logged in, there is no such cookie then?

Comment: That is correct. But I can see that the cookie is there from the Developer Console in Chrome

Comment: So it just says “Array ( )” then as the result of your print_r debug output? If it shows nothing at all, that would mean your print_r would not even get executed ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved. Turns out that disabling the cache in WPEngine wasn't actually turning it off 100%. WPEngine still had to add an exclusion for the cookie I was setting.

Comment: WP Engine had to add exclusions for my cookies and that seemed to fix the problem. Thanks!